# How can I catch 'n. def' exception (example: Sqrt of negative double number)

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, exception, sqrt

```
Dim number As Double = 0
Dim result As Double = 0

number = -10
Try
    result = Math.Sqrt(number)

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("ex = " & ex.ToString)
End Try

MsgBox("result = " & result)
```

When running this code snippet I get: `result = n. def` instead of catching the exception.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.Sqrt` does not thrown an exception if the input value is negative [as detailed here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sqrt(v=vs.110).aspx)

But you can just check that the value is valid after the sqrt and throw your own exception if not

`Double.IsNaN` returns `True` if the value is "[Not a Number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan(v=vs.110).aspx)":

```
    Dim number As Double = 0
    Dim result As Double = 0
    number = -10
    Try
        result = Math.Sqrt(number)
        If Double.IsNaN(result) Then Throw New Exception("Square root cannot be calculated for the value " & number)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("ex = " & ex.ToString)
    End Try

    MsgBox("result = " & result)
```

Note that you will still get the second message box displaying though even if an exception is thrown, so I would suggest something like this might be better:

```
    Dim number As Double = 0
    Dim result As Double = 0
    number = -10
    Try
        result = Math.Sqrt(number)
        If Double.IsNaN(result) Then
            MsgBox("ex = " & "Square root cannot be calculated for the value " & number)
        Else
            MsgBox("result = " & result)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("ex = " & ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine because there is no exception to catch.

As stated in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.math.sqrt(v=vs.110).aspx), `Math.Sqrt` returns [Double.NaN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.math.sqrt(v=vs.110).aspx) when passed a negative parameter; it does **not** throw any sort of exception.

`Double.NaN.ToString()` will return `n. def.` when the current culture is German ("de-DE").